# Passing by Reference in JavaScript(Call Method)

Tags: javascript, prototype, pass-by-reference

my problem here that i don't understand how does the method called "objectchanger" works
here is the source

```
function test()
{
  this.value=5;
}

test.prototype.Add=function()
{
  this.value++;
};

var obj = new test();

obj.Add();

alert(obj.value);


function objectchanger(fnc, obj)
{
  fnc.call(obj); 
  //obj.fnc(); >> without this line of code it works fine but why?????
  //why i don't need to write this code --
}

objectchanger(obj.Add, obj);
alert(obj.value); // the value is now 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` is a method on the `Function` object. It calls a function with the passed-in object as the `this` value in the function. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on call.

So when `objectchanger` calls `fnc.call(obj)`, it is calling `test.prototype.Add.call(obj)`, which is the same as calling `obj.Add()`.

Answer (score 0):

When the "this" object is accessed within a javascript function, it takes it from the current executing context. By passing the "obj" in the call method, the "this" object within the function is set to the passed in object.